# Issues loading file in Karma with Jasmine

Tags: three.js, karma-jasmine

for my tests of some three.js code with karma and jasmine I try to load some testdata via URL however even though the url is available it always fails loading  when I run karma with an error

```
beforeAll(function(done) {
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();

    loader.load( 'http://localhost/tests/testdata/cube_big.stl', 
        function ( geo ) {
            ... some code
            done();
        }, 
        function(e){
            console.log("progress");
            console.log(e);
        }, 
        function(e){ 
            console.log("error case");
            console.log(e);
        }
    );
});
```

Funny thing is that via specrunner webpage of jasmine I can happily execute this in the browser and everything works nicely. Only if I use karma runner I get fails
Error in those cases is not very clear to me as it reads `ProgressEvent{isTrusted: true}`

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `STLLoader` internally uses `FileLoader` which uses `XMLHttpRequest` for file loading. This is a browser API and not supported in `node.js`.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to load geometries from Karma in that case?

Comment: You can try to load the file via `fs` and then call the `STLLoader.parse()` method manually.

Comment: BTW: Please accept the answer since it solves your original question.